# Is there a standard function like `>>`, but returning the result of the first operand?

Tags: haskell, monads, standard-library

For instance, suppose I want to read a line and also ring a bell:

```
λ getLine >> putChar '\007'
How lang and dreary is the night when I am frae my Dearie.
-- Blip and `()`. The line is lost.
λ getLine >>= (\x -> putChar '\007' >> return x
I restless lie frae e'en to morn though I were ne'er sae weary.
"I restless lie frae e'en to morn though I were ne'er sae weary."
-- A line and also a blip side effect.
```

The idea seems to have much in common with `const`, the only difference being that the values given are effectful, and are both executed, even though only the value of the first action is retained. *(Unlike with `>>`, which retains the value from the second.)* What I mean exactly is this:

```
λ constM a b = a >>= \x -> b >> return x
```

Here is a more complex example, involving parsers from `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`:

```
λ readP_to_S (many1 (munch1 (not . isSpace) `constM` skipSpaces ) `constM` eof) <$> getLine
How slow ye move, ye heavy hours.
[(["How","slow","ye","move,","ye","heavy","hours."],"")]
```

I wonder if this function is available in `base`, or easily constructible from other functions in `base`.

Comment: Furthermore in the context of `IO`, there is the `finally`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:finally. But this is more used in combination with the *exception* mechanism, so is is not semantically entirely the same.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can I ask you to undelete the previous comments, or, even better, consolidate them into leftaroundabout's answer? They are of value.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info for info on hoogle and other FAQs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a
```

Comment: Please put some explanation, that helps.

Comment: @Prateek I don't see what's to explain for a question that asks “what standard function is equivalent to `\a b -> a >>= \x -> b >> return x`”, if it can be answered fully with “`(<*)` is”. I actually find it a bit silly that this trivial answer to a trivial question is upvoted so much, but here we go.